# How to remove un-parenthesized URLs from a <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

The code within the attached fiddle removes all URLs within a `<textarea>`.

Is it possible for the code to remove all URLs, except if the URL is inside of a parentheses — *e.g.* (google.com) — within the `<textarea>` dynamically?

If possible, I would be appreciate an updated fiddle as I am new to coding.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#txtarea").keyup(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/mg, ' ');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="txtarea" placeholder="How to stop http being entered into textarea?"></textarea>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/9/)

Comment: You will probably want to use regular expressions, but checking an URL is a hard problem (the brackets however will be very easy). Hopefully it is also a frequent problem so you should have no difficulty finding existing answers.

Comment: _"however, keep the URL's that are inside of a bracket e.g. (google.com)"_ Inside of bracket characters `"["` , `"]"` ?

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/10/). Paste `(test http://google.com) here` into the text area. Note that if you type `(`, then `http://google.com`, the URL will get deleted because it is still not inside `(...)`. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @stribizhev your fiddle doesn't seem up to the mark. Try putting `(http://awesome.com) htt p://awesome.com` to your textarea. Anyway's i've updated the answer below to get the exact results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Please use the following code for the above (*string containing single url*).

```
   $(function(){
    var urlmatch = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/gm, protomatch = /\((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?\)/gm;
    $("#txtarea").keyup(function(){
        if( this.value.match(protomatch) && this.value.charAt(0) == '(' && this.value.charAt(this.value.length-1) == ')' ){
            this.value = this.value;
        }
        else if(this.value.match(urlmatch) && !this.value.match(protomatch) && this.value.charAt(0) != '(' && this.value.charAt(this.value.length-1) != ')'){
            this.value = this.value.replace(urlmatch, '');
        }
    })
});
```

**Edit:** It'll check and remove all the very next urls(*multiple urls*) coming throughout the string.

```
       $(function(){
                $("#txtarea").keyup(function(){    
                    var urlmatch = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/, newA = [], a = this.value.split(' '); 
                $.each(a, function (i, j) {//j = $.trim(j); 
                if((j.match(urlmatch) && j.charAt(0) == '(' && j.charAt(j.length-1) == ')') != false) {
                newA.push(j)
                }
                console.log(j, '->', j.match(urlmatch) && j.charAt(0) == '(' && j.charAt(j.length-1) == ')'  ) })

                var o = newA.join(" ")
                this.value = o;
                })
            });
```

Find the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/19/) for this. Cheers!

Comment: when you start to type your url in parenthese : `( http://google.co` will be delete before i can type the closing parenthese ! sorry but this is not a valid answer.

Comment: The only problem is the bracket e.g. (www.google.com) works correctly by not removing the URL. However, when typing another URL next to the bracket such as, (www.google.com) www.google.com, the URL not inside of the bracket will not be removed. Is it possible for the URL inside of the bracket to remain, however, to ensure URLs that are not within the bracket are removed from the <textarea>?

Comment: The new code will check and remove every url from the string not just one. :)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle update! However, the only problem now is within the <textarea>, the code will not allow to press enter to leave a line gap. Is it possible to still have the option to press enter to create a space?

Comment: All right @Dave. Check now, enter/returns are being allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the updated fiddle. The only problem now, is when text pasted with links seems to freeze the fiddle. Is it possible, to resolve this issue as it was not occurring in the earlier fiddles?

Comment: No nothing's such issue here. It's damn fast performance wise. But if you've any then just edit and run it on your environment.

Comment: @AkshayaRaghuvanshi - The code above works perfectly. Thank You!  However, I have managed to fix the problem if the fiddle freezes when several URLs are pasted into the textarea. ***[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/26/)***